# How to create UICollectionView with center cell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I necessary to develop such object.
UICollectionView Horizontal must center cell. And at the same center cell is marked.
As well on the picture:

[image: UICollectionView centertred Cell is selected]

Comment: On didSelectItemAtIndexPath, change the offset?

Comment: Yes, then cell is centralized. But not is selected center cell and not go to selected cell if open view.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have saved the last selected cell as a number variable named `savedSelection`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let idxPath = IndexPath(row: savedSelection, section: 0)

    let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: idxPath)
    cell?.isSelected = true
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: idxPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: It is always the one that is selected in the middle? Or I must click on it and then select it?

Comment: I'm assuming that first, no cell is selected... next, the user scrolls left/right, and selects a cell - you save that in a variable... then you go to another view... when you come back, you use the saved variable to auto-scroll the cell to the center, and to auto-select it.

Comment: This works and should be marked as the correct answer. Updated for Swift 5.